# Error: The argument type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>?'

Tags: flutter

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wq4bp.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oz8T2.png)`I want to access list from the currincies but fail`

Comment: It is preferred to post code blocks instead of screenshots of code.

Comment: function return type should be `List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change :

```
List<DropDownMenuItem>
```

with:

```
List<DropDownMenuItem<String>>
```

in the function type.